# Seaside redirect for render not working on physical iOS devices

Tags: ios, smalltalk, seaside

We're having a problem with physical *iOS* devices (works fine on Chrome virtual device) where a final Seaside redirect is not happening after an Azure SSO redirect.
I'd like to understand what triggers the Seaside redirect: I can see it in normal rendering, but I've never had to dig into it like this before.

When I log from a non-iOS device I see...

1 - `WAApplication>>handleFiltered: application URL`

- `self requestContext redirectTo: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/...'`
- redirects back to our app URL with an access token

2 -`WAApplication>>handleFiltered: application URL with MS access token & no _s & _k values`

- validate token with Azure
- save user info in new `WASession`
- finish render

3 - `WAApplication>>handleFiltered: application URL with _s & _k` plus callback values like: `&2=2160&1=3840&3=false`

- `WAResponse>>location: application URL with _s & new _k` and no callback values

4 - `WAApplication>>handleFiltered: application URL with _s & _K`

- finish render

With *iOS* **step 3** does **not** happen; I'd like to know what triggers it normally.

Just to add to the fun, we have a two `WAApplication` registered. The default application fails on *iOS*, the other works fine. I can see no obvious difference between the two.

Thanks for any help (I'll cross post on the the Seaside mailing list and Discord)

Comment: If you have two applications from which one works and one not; what about checking the traffic with Wireshark to see the difference in replies?

Comment: Are you using any cookies that might be blocked on iOS? I presume by "iOS" you mean Safari? Have you tried with another browser on iOS? Is the request that you see for 3 being sent from the browser? You should see it in the debugger (you can attach Safari on a Mac to the physical device).

Comment: Problem is on all browsers on any iOS device: I've tried Safari, Edge and Chrome. Tracing the communication is what I'm at now, but the problem is a lack of a redirect. What I'm digging into is the where Seaside generates the redirect. Always knew it worked that way, but until now didn't need to know the details.

Comment: fwiw: looking at WARenderPhaseContinuation>>processRendering: I see the same content for both the iOS and Windows initial request. And I see that with iOS the following WACallbackProcessingActionContinuation does not happen, as it does with Windows... that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is caused by a seven year old method that used a `window.location.href=` to gather device characteristics, like screen size and touch support. Removing that `href` fixes the problem with iOS. Lots of other & cleaner ways to get the data.
Quick fix is to wrap the `href` with a `setTimeout` for *200 ms*.

Comment: As your problem is solved, I think you should be able to mark this answer as "accepted".

Comment: It would be nice if you would elaborate on the way you have found out the issue.

Comment: I traced through Seaside. We develop VW and deploy in GS. In our VW model I can start a session with a &start= parameter which mimics the Azure redirect. I used the URL with the start= option in a browser with developer tools open and traced the web requests. The iOS trace for GS did not have an explicit redirectUrl: after the the screen size render method. which led me to dig into iOS issues with href=, where I found suggestions for using setTimeout() ... big thanks to everyone that posted answers and comments on iOS redirect; finding them made all the difference